# ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de llamar a determinada función en base a una variable?

Tags: python

Supongamos que tengo una variable que me la da el usuario, y dependiendo del valor de esta, quiero hacer una u otra cosa. Va un ejemplo sencillo:

```
input = str(input('login/logout: '))
```

si `input` es... digamos, "login", quiero que se ejecute la función `login()`, si la variable es logout, quiero que se ejecute `logout()`. Quizás tenga la respuesta frente a mi nariz, pero llevo un rato y no se me ocurre una buena manera.
Mi pregunta aquí realmente es, como harían para afrontar eso de la manera mas eficiente (sin if's)?

Ya intente con un objeto/dict pero se llaman las funciones automáticamente:

```
temp = {
    'login': print('login'),
    'logout': print('logout')
}
```

Ejecución: (pasando como input el string 'test')

```
>> login/logout: test
login
logout
```

PD: Lo siento si es una pregunta estúpida, no le encuentro la solución y siento que la tengo frente a mi :( y son las 2AM.

Comment: Llamalo loginInloginout. O LogInOut. Si es una var toggler es buen nombre el que tiene sus dos posibles respuestas. Así sabes que hace esa var más rápido

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La forma más directa y clara es una simple secuencia de `if/elif/else`, que es lo más parecido que Python tiene (¡de momento! ver **bonus**) a lo que otros lenguajes llaman un `switch`.

Sería así:

```
def login():
  print("login")

def logout():
  print("logout")

def no_valido():
  print("Opción no válida")

caso = input("Qué quieres hacer? ")

if caso.lower() == "login":
  login()
elif caso.lower() == "logout":
  logout()
else:
  no_valido()
```

La opción con diccionarios que intentabas también es posible, pero **no tienes que llamar** a las funciones cuando las asignas a claves de diccionario. Lo que asignas es simplemente el nombre de la función (si la llamas estarías asignando en cambio el valor retornado por la función). Es decir:

```
casos = {
  "login": login,
  "logout": logout
}
```

Y ahora usarías el diccionario del modo siguiente. Con `.get()` puedes sacar el valor asociado a una clave (y también especificar un valor por defecto si esa clave no existe en el diccionario). El valor extraido será una función, *que llamarás después*. Es decir:

```
caso = input("Qué quieres hacer? ")
funcion = casos.get(caso.lower(), no_valido)
funcion()
```

## Bonus

La futura versión de python, 3.10, que ya se puede probar en su versión inestable de desarrollo, implementará una nueva estructura de control, superficialemnte similar al `switch` de otros lenguajes, pero mucho más potente.

Usando esta característica el código podría quedar así:

```
caso = input("Qué quieres hacer? ")

match caso.lower():
  case "login":
      print("login")
  case "logout":
      print("logout")
  case _:
      print("Opción no válida")
```

Observa que tras cada `case`  aparece un bloque de código que puede contener varias instrucciones si lo precisas, por lo que no sería necesario aquí definir funciones previas como en el caso del diccionario. Fíjate también en la sintaxis especial del caso "default".

Aunque superficialmente se parece a un `switch`, es mucho más potente porque los "casos" con los que encajas no se limitan a valores literales. Pueden ser otras variables, expresiones, o en el caso más genérico, patrones estructurales. Tienes los detalles técnicos en la [PEP 622](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622) y varios ejemplos de uso en la [PEP 636](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/)

Para que veas que va más allá de un `switch`, mira un ejemplo de qué otras cosas podrías hacer:

```
match caso.lower():
  case "login" | "entrar":
      print("login")
  case "logout" | "salir":
      print("logout")
  case _:
      print("Opción no válida")
```

O este otro:

```
match caso.lower().split():
  case ["login"]:
      print("login en localhost")
  case ["login", machine]:
      print("Login en", machine)
  case ["logout"]:
      print("logout")
  case _:
      print("Opción no válida")
```

Ejemplos de ejecución:

```
Qué quieres hacer? login
login en localhost

Qué quieres hacer? login remote
Login en remote

Qué quieres hacer? logout
logout

Qué quieres hacer? logout remote
Opción no válida

Qué quieres hacer? login foo bar
Opción no válida
```

Comment: Muy interesante la estructura `match`, gracias por los links!

Comment: Gracias por la explicación!

Comment: ¿y la parte de sin if?

Comment: @tincopasan A qué te refieres? He puesto tres formas de hacerlo, la primera (aunque lleva if) es la más recomendable, pero luego muestro también cómo hacerlo correctamente en base a diccionarios, y también cómo se podrá hacer a partir de la versión 3.10.

Comment: @abulafia lo de versiones nuevas de python, ponele, está en él usarlas, pero en su planteo dijo explicitamente sin if , más allá de que te parezca lo más recomendable no está en su pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres hacerlo con un diccionario, podrías hacerlo así:

```py
def saludo():
    print('Hola')

def despedida():
    print('Adios')

temp = {
    'login': saludo,
    'logout': despedida,
}

entrada = input('login/logout: ')
temp[entrada]()
```

Como puedes ver, a cada elemento del diccionario, en lugar de asignarle una variable le asignamos una función `'login': saludo`. Luego al acceder al elemento, ponemos los paréntesis porque es una llamada a la función `temp[entrada]()`

Dicho esto, lo que estamos haciendo es una forma básica de una clase. Por lo que quizá para lo que quieres te venga mejor [declarar una clase](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) con los métodos y propiedades que necesites.

Comment: Gracias! Muy buena idea.

Comment: de esa forma dará un error si lo ingresado no coincide exactamente con las claves del diccionario

Comment: @tincopasan sí, lo sé, pero pones un `try-catch` y ya, no quería poner demasiado código que pueda distraer de la explicación.

Answer (score -1):

se me ocurren muchas formas, pero ya que tenés un diccionario:

1 Elimino el print del diccionario

2 creo la función a llamar y lo hago desde el diccionario

3 llamo a la clave del diccionario

```
def saludo():
    return "bienvenido"

temp = {
    'login': saludo,
    'logout': 'logout'
}



entrada = input('login/logout: ')

print(temp.get(entrada)())
```

Eso es básicamente lo que entendí del planteo.

Dicho sea de paso input ya devuelve una cadena

Comment: Esto ejecuta la función `saludo()` al momento de asignar valores al diccionario, que supongo que no es lo que se busca. Puedes comprobarlo poniendo un print dentro de `saludo()`, verás que lo que sea que imprimas aparece antes de pedir el valor de la entrada. Imagina que las funciones realmente fueran `login()` y `logout()` , no parece aceptable el comportamiento.

Comment: @jachguate es un error mio por no revisar el código, el idle que uso agrega automáticamente los paréntesis al poner el nombre la función y al copiar y pegar ni me fije.

Comment: Entonces, edita tu respuesta para quitarlos, eso la hará, al menos, válida. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate no es necesario, fijate que alguien hizo básicamente lo mismo unas horas después que mi código y ese está bien.

Comment: Hombre, no dejaría un bug en una respuesta, como tampoco lo dejaría en un programa (se haya introducido por accidente o no). Si lo editas, no dejes de comentarme, te di un voto negativo que con gusto quitaría si la respuesta fuese correcta. Un saludo.